# Validation for Terms and Conditions check box

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, checkbox

This is my 
[My JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gUCcd/2/)

I am attempting to add a class when the checkbox is clicked, though I can not seem to figure out how to do it in a way that will fit into the code i already have.

CODE:

```
  $(this).live("change keyup", function () {

  var checkbox = $('#termscons').prop(':checked');

  if (currid == "termcons") {

                if (checkbox == 'checked') {
                    infobox.html("Accepted!");
                    infobox.addClass('good');
                } else if (checkbox !== 'checked') {
                    infobox.html(replacehtml);
                    infobox.removeClass('good');
                }
            }  

         if ($('#termscons').next().hasClass('good')) {

            $("#sendbtn").css("display", "block");
        } else {
            $("#sendbtn").css("display", "none");

        }
```

Comment: Just a thought: Make sure they've scrolled all the way down is one way that doesn't really go against UX. making them _wait_, say 1 minute, before accepting goes against UX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, don't use `live`, it's deprecated, instead use `on`, for example

```
$(document).on('change', '#termscons', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // checked, so you can add class, i.e.
        infobox.addClass('good');
        // other code
    }
    else {
        // not checked
        infobox.removeClass('good');
        // other code
    }
});
```

This also answers, how you can add/remove a `class` depending on the `checkbox`'s state.

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/tjE24/1/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gUCcd/5/ this is the entire code i am using. how would i implement it into this? i had a go just then.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is trying to access the prop of `:checked` which should be `checked`
I copied this from a website 
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-check-if-checkbox-is-checked.html

```
  // First way
    $('#checkBox').attr('checked');
    // If using jQuery 1.6 or up use .prop() instead
    // Learn the difference between property and an attribute
    $('#checkBox').prop('checked');

    // Second way 
    $('#edit-checkbox-id').is(':checked'); 

    // Third way for jQuery 1.2
    $("input[@type=checkbox][@checked]").each( 
        function() { 
           // Insert code here 
        } 
    );
    // Third way == UPDATE jQuery 1.3
    $("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each( 
        function() { 
           // Insert code here 
        } 
    );

    // In his comment Andy mentions that the 3rd method
    // does not work in Firefox 3.5.2 & jQuery 1.3.2
```

I hope this can help :)

Comment: I've have had a go at using a lot of methods i have done {checked} & {:checked} neither have worked for me.

Comment: Please make a fiddle for just the check box so we can help more because the code there is too large :)

Comment: sorry Sedz had to pop out to work. thats pretty much what i wanted it to do but it didn't have to show the message.

Comment: Hey Sedz `console.log` gets information from the browser, so it will only add class good on second click because it needs information first. I need it so that it is on first click. so what would i use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you have a few issues. Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gUCcd/4/)

1. You bind to the focus event of all text boxes and then, within the handler, you try to bind to the change event of the current textbox, expecting the your check box to be one of textboxes.)
2. you are binding to the wrong event for a checkbox. Use `click`.
3. your check for prop(":checked") is wrong. Use `is` instead.

   ```
     $("#termscons").click(function(){
               var infobox = $(this).next();
               var checkbox = $(this).is(':checked');

               // we use this logic to check the subject
               if (checkbox) {
                   infobox.html("Accepted!");
                   infobox.addClass('good');
               } else {
                   infobox.html("");
                   infobox.removeClass('good');
               }
   });
   ```

Comment: What did you do, and why does that fix the issue?